# How to send Alt-Tab through the Putty?

Tags: putty, keys

I want to use bash completion for command parameters on a remote computer.

How can I send Alt-Tab combination in Putty? Is there other key combinations for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press and release <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Most of the time, holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> simply causes the terminal (PuTTY) to send ESC (0x1B) before the pressed key, as you can see yourself by running `cat > /dev/null` and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Any key</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

Try <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  That's two keystrokes, not a chord.